# Resize Photoshop canvas to fit selected layer's (larger) dimensions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I know how to crop, to fit a selected layer's dimensions that are smaller than my canvas, but is there an easy way to upsize my canvas to fit a selected object that is larger than it?  Can I find out the selected layer's dimensions easily, so I could manually resize my canvas?

Example:

[image: canvas]

I have selected an image that I placed into my document, by <kbd>CMD</kbd> + Clicking on its thumbnail in the layers palette.  I need to resize my document to fit the selected artwork.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is holding `cmd` while left clicking the bigger layer, and afterwards press `C` to crop to the selected area. This should make the canvas the same size as the selected layer.

Comment: I feel like an idiot.  I should have known that.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Comment: this works good ;)

Comment: Amazing workaround